# Calculate Cell Height without Using Fixed Values

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I need to calculate the height for a UITableViewCell with includes multiple rows of wrapping text. So far I couldn't find a 100% exact way to do this. Furthermore the technique I currently use relies heavily on fixed values:

```
NSString *cellText;    
cellText = @"Very long multi line text in this String ...";
UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
return labelSize.height + 32;
```

Fixed values used in just in these few lines:

- Fontsize (14)
- Font Type (Helvetica)
- CGSize, Width (280.0f)
- Random padding value that I found is needed (32)

**Is there a nice way to rewrite this in a way that all these fixed values are fetched and calculated dynamically?**

That would help a lot to make the layout more responsive and the code reusable going forward. I appreciate any best practices.

Comment: A little ol' googlin will help: http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/how-to-multiline-label-ios-objective-c/

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems good but u missed is cell appropriate calculation.U need to add label's topmost postion and label's bottommost postion in cell(parentView).

Just calculate like this

```
 return labelSize.height + 2*yourLabelInCell.frame.origin.y  //here label's topmost postion and label's bottommost postion in cell added
```

Label will adjust appropriately in cell.